# How to show specific values on a select depending of other value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select on AngularJS in which I show states that I get from an API. These states are the possible states of a contract.

I also get the contracts with the actual state of each contract from the API. I want that depending of this state that I am getting from the API, only specific values will be shown.

For example, if I am getting `Accept` value from the API I want that only `Accept` and `No Accept` options will be shown on the `select`. Same situation with `In progress` and `CancelProgress` options.

To get in situation I have reproduce a simple example:

```js
function StatesController($scope) {
    $scope.contracts = [{
        IdContract: "1",
        ActualState: "No Accept"
      }, {
        IdContract: "2",
        ActualState: "In progress"
      }, {
        IdContract: "3",
        ActualState: "Accept"
      }];
      
    $scope.states = [{
          StateName: "Accept"
        }, {
          StateName: "No Accept"
        }, {
          StateName: "In progress",
        }, {
          StateName: "CancelProgress"
        }];
}
```

```css
table, th , td  {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="StatesController">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="contract in contracts">
      <td>{{contract.IdContract}}</td>
      <td>{{contract.ActualState}}</td>
      <td>
        <select ng-model="States" name="State">
            <option ng-repeat="state in states" ng-selected="state.StateName == contract.ActualState" value="{{state.StateName}}">{{state.StateName}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

In this particular case, only `In progress` and `CancelProgress` options should be available instead of all options.

How can I treat these select to show only specific values on AngularJS?

**P.S: I do not have access to the API so I cannot modify the response of it.**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to change the value of states depending on $scope.selected

I think the best approach is to create an API with the possible states for the selected state and use it to fill the select

eg

```
string[] getStates(int stateId)
```

Comment: I am sorry but I forgot to mention that I it is a client API that I cannot modify but yes, that is the idea. I am wondering if I can do it on the select using AngularJS.

Comment: create a service file on angularJS and define which are the desired states for a given state, then use this method instead of the whole list

Comment: I have modify a little bit my question to adapt it closer to my real case. The problem is that I do not know how to make a condition taking as reference the contract for each row of the table.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the API, you have no other choice than have a correspondance table on your side, listen to changes on $scope.selected and filter the array.

In the actuale state, if the state names don't change, you can filter the array on StateName.indexOf("accept") or StateName.indexOf("progress")

**EDIT:**

The only solution I see without modifying the model (by adding a stateType property for example) is to have one select element by state type (harcoded).

If contract is of type "progress" display a filtered select element.
If contract is of type "accept" display a filtered select element.

```js
function StatesController($scope) {
    $scope.contracts = [{
        IdContract: "1",
        ActualState: "No Accept"
      }, {
        IdContract: "2",
        ActualState: "In progress"
      }, {
        IdContract: "3",
        ActualState: "Accept"
      }];
      
    $scope.states = [{
          StateName: "Accept"
        }, {
          StateName: "No Accept"
        }, {
          StateName: "In progress",
        }, {
          StateName: "CancelProgress"
        }];
        
    $scope.stateType = function(type) {
      return $scope.states.filter(function(state) {
        return ~state.StateName.toLowerCase().indexOf(type);
      });
    }
    
    $scope.isType = function(contract, type) {
      return ~contract.ActualState.toLowerCase().indexOf(type);
    }
}
```

```css
table, th , td  {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

select {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="StatesController">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="contract in contracts">
      <td>{{contract.IdContract}}</td>
      <td>{{contract.ActualState}}</td>
      <td>
        <select ng-model="States" name="State" ng-show="isType(contract, 'accept')">
            <option ng-repeat="state in stateType('accept')" ng-selected="state.StateName == contract.ActualState" value="{{state.StateName}}">{{state.StateName}}</option>
        </select>
        <select ng-model="States" name="State" ng-show="isType(contract, 'progress')">
            <option ng-repeat="state in stateType('progress')" ng-selected="state.StateName == contract.ActualState" value="{{state.StateName}}">{{state.StateName}}</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

To make things a little cleaner, you could also dynamically add a property stateType to each of the contracts in the array you get from the API.

This way I think you can get rid of the 2 selects and just filter the array in the second ng-repeat.

Comment: I guess that I should filter it on the controller, right?

Comment: Yes, you get all possible states and filter when you retrieve the selected. I don't see other possibilities.

Comment: Can you make an example about how can I implement it with my example, please? I do not understand you at all how you want to implement that filter.

Comment: I added a snippet

Comment: What does really do the `~` before state?

Comment: indexOf(xxx) > -1 (bitwise operator looks cleaner to me)